# GetChanges() Or RowState to get all changes of a datatable?

Tags: c#, winforms

In a **Winforms** application I have to **log all changes in datagrid (datatable)**. In other words I want to to get all changes, since it has been loaded. For this I want to use **Datatable.GetChanges()**. I know, that with **GetChanges()** I get a datatable containing a copy of all rows in the original DataSet that have pending changes.

My question is now, if it is also possible to get more **additional information of the changes**. For example I want to know if a **row** has been **added** or **deleted** or only has been **updated**. If a row has been **updated** I also want to know which cells has been updated? Is there a way to get all this information quickly or does I have to do a **deep comparison** row by row with the **original datatable**?

Or is it better to use **RowState** to get all changes?

Answer (score 11):

For the row addition/deletion check [RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate)

For each item in the row (aka the cell) check [DataRowVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135373)

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dr.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
            {
                var changedCols = new List<DataColumn>();
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    if (!dr[dc, DataRowVersion.Original].Equals(
                         dr[dc, DataRowVersion.Current])) /* skipped Proposed as indicated by a commenter */
                    {
                        changedCols.Add(dc);
                    }
                }
                // now handle the changedCols list
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A couple of remarks: 1) You need to use Equals(), because "!=" will compare references of returned objects (and will return false even if the objects contain same value). 2) I had to use DataRowVersion.Current instead of DataRowVersion.Proposed, because DataRowVersion.Proposed threw an exception.

Comment: Equals() will not work if the value has been changed to the same value. You need to use ReferenceEquals() to be sure that it has been changed.

Comment: @LachlanEnnis I beg to differ. The types that are likely to be present in those columns have their own override of Equals and will handle both reference and value equallity correctly for their type. Using ReferenceEquals might give me false positives if the valuetype needs to be boxed, in which case their references will never be equal.

Comment: @rene if I use GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified) and the cell that was changed was changed to the same value, then how do you know it was changed? I am dealing with this exact scenario right now where both Equals and ReferenceEquals aren't working for a string type. Where as an integer seemed to work with ReferenceEquals and not Equals.

Comment: "Changed to the same value" ... that doesn't sound as a change. And that your integer "works" with referenceequals is exactly due to the boxing I mentioned earlier.  Why Equals doesn't work for your scenario is unclear. maybe produce an [mcve] and ask a question about it.

Comment: I have re-thought the logic of my example to avoid the "change to the same value" issue. Also thank you for the explanation. It has been really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Each `DataRow` in the resulting DataTable will have its [`RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx) property set, which tells you whether the row was added, deleted, or updated.

I do not believe individual cells provide update information, however - it's only tracked by row.